# Predictive modelling - Regression with grouped id's and moving average (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a problem with a predictive modelling problem. Hopefully, someone have time and can help me. The starting position is shown below. S1-S2 are sensor measurements and RUL is my target value.

### DataStructure:

```
id period s1       s2       s3        RUL
1  1      510.23   643.43   1585.29   6
1  2      512.34   644.89   1586.12   5
1  3      514.65   645.11   1587.99   4
1  4      512.98   647.59   1588.45   3
1  5      516.34   649.04   1590.65   2
1  6      518.12   652.62   1593.09   1
2  1      509.77   640.61   1584.91   9
2  2      510.26   642.06   1586.00   8
2  3      511.95   643.62   1588.09   7 
2  4      513.51   646.51   1589.45   6
2  5      512.17   648.06   1589.54   5
2  6      515.56   646.11   1586.22   4
2  7      518.78   649.34   1586.96   3
2  8      519.90   650.30   1588.95   2
2  9      521.05   651.39   1591.34   1
3  1      501.11   653.99   1580.45   8
3  2      511.45   643.23   1584.09   7
3  3      505.45   643.78   1586.11   6
3  4      504.45   643.43   1588.34   5 
3  5      506.45   643.71   1589.89   4
3  6      511.45   643.33   1591.21   3
3  7      516.45   643.61   1592.42   2
3  8      518.45   643.05   1596.77   1
```

### Target:

My target is to predict the remaining usefull live (RUL) of unseen data. In this case I have only 1 type of machine with different id's (That means 1 type and 3 different physical systems). For the prediction the id doesn't matter, because it's the same machine. Furthermore, I want to add new features. The moving average of s1 s2 and s3. So I have to add three new column with the names a1, a2 and a3.

For instance, a1 should look like:

```
a1
NaN
NaN
512.41
513.32
514.66
515.81
NaN
NaN
510.66
511.91
512.54
513.75
515.50
518.08
519.91
NaN
NaN
506.00
507.12
505.45
507.45
511.45
515.45
```

The next problem is, that I can't work with NaN, because it's a string. How can I ignore/work with it for a1, a2, and a3 ?

Next Question is: How can I use a regression models like RandomForest and Bagged Decision Trees with a train_test_split to predict the RUL of unseen new data? (Of course I need more data, this example gives just the structure.) [s1],[s2],[s3] are my inputs and RUL is the output.
Furthermore, I want to evaluate the model with Mean Absolut Error, Mean Squared Error and R².

Finaly, I want to use the gridsearch Method for tuning.

### Thank you:

Thank you in advance. I know what I wanna do, but I'm not able to realize it with python. A complete code would be perfect.

Comment: `NaN` is not a string, and Pandas knows to ignore it.  That is, if you do `pandas.DataFrame({'one':[5,numpy.NaN,7]}).mean()` you'll get back `6.0` as the answer.  That may vary if you're working with non-Pandas methods though, but can usually be specified.  Also, if you show something you tried that didn't work it might be more informative for people trying to answer.  Are you using scikit-learn?

Comment: Yes I'm using scikit-learn. The problem is, that a lot of training-exercises are very simple. But when u have an other case, there are so many thing, where I have no clue about. That's why I'm asking here - to get a prime example. And thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of solving this problem is through imputation. SciKitLearn has a built in package for imputation. The documentation is here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html

There are 3 strategies for replacing the NaNs: 
1) replacing it with the mean of the column
2) replacing it with the mode of the column
3) replacing it with the median of the column

An example of usage would look like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(strategy = 'mean', axis = 1)
a1 = Imputer.fit_transform(a1, strategy = 'mean')
```

There are also usage examples available here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation

Comment: Thank u. Your answer explain how to deal with NaN.
But how can I create three new column (a1, a2, a3) with the moving average (w=3) grouped by each ID as shown in the example?

Comment: `mova = df.groupby('id').s1
rolls = [3]
df['a1'] = pd.concat([mova.rolling(i).mean() for i in rolls], axis=1, keys=rolls).values` would be the complete answer to the moving average case. (for 1 column)